# Is there a way to "simulate" opening a file with sublime and saving with a particular encoding via command line?

Tags: command-line, python, sublime-text, encoding

I have a csv file which is utf8 format. However, I am unable to read it into python with the pandas package.

I noticed however, if I open the file in sublime, and the "Save with Encoding" --> UTF-8, and then I try to read the file into python with the pandas package it works!

Note the file is originally detected as UTF-8 (I used uchardet to determine this). So any idea how I can accomplish the above without actually opening sublime? I.e. is there a command line method to do this (I also tried iconv and it does not do the trick, only sublime does).

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question - but have you examined the file before and after (perhaps using a hex editor) to try to figure out what sublime is changing, exactly? That might give a clue to how to do the same with command line tools - maybe even with a modified `iconv` command.

Comment: Since you seem to know your way around Python, have you considered writing a custom Sublime Text plugin that will convert all files of a certain type? It should be fairly easy with `on_load()` and `set_encoding()` (see the [API Reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html))

Comment: @idleberg thanks I will take a look into this. I also found the root of the problem which was a carriage return character in the data '\r'. After I delete that, I am able to read the data with the pandas package. I guess sublime must be doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```